# Compare Dictionary Key of type string to another string in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm actually trying to check if a `string` is equal to any of the key's in my `Dictionary` object.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
using (var oStreamReader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    Dictionary<String, String> typeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    typeNames.Add("Kind","nvarchar(1000)");
    typeNames.Add("Name","nvarchar(1000)");
    DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();

    var headLine = oStreamReader.ReadLine().Trim().Replace("\"", ""); 
    var columnNames = headLine.Split(new[] { ';' });

    String[] oStreamDataValues;

    /*
    *create DataTable header with specific datatypes and names
    */

    int countCol = 0;

    foreach (string readColumn in columnNames)
    {


        if ((readColumn.ToString().Replace("\"", "").CompareTo(typeNames) == true))
        {
            // this comparison doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question right; where is the dictionary you mention in the problem description? Are you referring to the `DataTable`?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to post it, I have defined the dictionary in another place i will edit it now

Comment: Try this `if (typeNames.All(x => x == readColumn))`

Comment: This depends on the fact if you either want to check against all the keys, than you have to iterate over all keys of the dictionary and compare it with `readColumn` or if you want to compare against the values, than you have to do the same with the values of the dictionary.

Comment: Do you want check if exist the key or value?

Comment: It is important to know if you want to search for a key or a value. Searching for the key is built-in, it's kinda what the dictionary is for in the first place. Searching for a value is not, however, but then why are you using a dictionary that goes in the wrong direction for this?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm looking for the key

Comment: Side note: Your task might be easier to solve using [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If you're looking for the key, simply use `typeNames.ContainsKey` or `typeNames.TryGetValue` or one of the other methods on the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this (by inspiration of Paul Houlston and Thomas Lielacher)

```
string headLine = oStreamReader.ReadLine().Trim().Replace("\"", ""); 
string columnNames = headLine.Split(new[] { ';' });

foreach (string readColumn in columnNames)
{
    if (typeNames.Keys.Contains(readColumn, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
    {
       DataColumn oDataColumn = new DataColumn(readColumn,typeof(System.String));
       oDataTable.Columns.Add(oDataColumn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not quite sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you have a C# dictonary you can use linq to check for values that match the required value, e.g.

```
string valueToCompare = "Value to match";
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string> 
                                  {
                                    {"Key 1", "A value"}, 
                                    {"Key 2", "Another value"}
                                  };
bool found= dict.Values
                .Any(value 
                     => 
                     value.Equals(valueToCompare,
                                  StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                    );
```

Comment: I have no experience with LINQ because I'm a former java Developer and just started to work with C#. But thank's I will try it

Comment: or just: `bool valueIsFound = dict.Values.Contains(valueToCompare, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Shouldn't it be dict.Keys.Any(...) as the so is asking for whether a string that matches any of the keys in their dictionary object?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want check if exist an entry in your Dictionary that as the same key of one of the values in your `columnNames` object I suggest you to use [ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htszx2dy.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string keyvalue;
            if (d.ContainsKey("value to find"))
            {
                if (d.TryGetValue("value to find", out keyvalue))
                {
                    //// here keyvalue variable has the value 
                }
                else
                {
                    ///value is null or throws exception
                }
            }
            else
            {
                    ////key no exists
            }
```